# How to dynamically create an EJS file from a database

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, routes, ejs

New web developer here; I am working with Mongo/Express/Node.

I am trying to make an e-commerce site where the admin will create new "categories" and add them to the database.

Whenever a new "category" is added to the database, I want a new EJS page to be created for that category (and all other categories in the database), that will then load all of the "products" that are of that category in that EJS page.

The category page should conform to a template; only changing its name and the products that are loaded into it.

Something like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <h2>Categories</h2>
            <div class="menu">
                <a>Men</a>
                <a>Women</a>
                <a>Children</a>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <% products.forEach(function(product) { %>
            <% if (product.category === x) { %>
                <h5><%= product.name %></h5>
                <img src='someurl'>
            <% } %>
        <% }) %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily you don't need to dynamically create EJS files. You can use [parameterised route matching](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) and then return the right data for that category in the render function of the EJS page. That's the beauty of using dynamic web pages!

**`server.js`**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/example/:category", (req, res) => {
    let { category } = req.params;
    let products = /* search db for category that matches that "category" var */;
    res.render("products.ejs", { products });
});
```

**`products.ejs`**

```
...
<% products.forEach(product => { %>
    <h5><%= product.name %></h5>
    <img src="<%= product.imageURL %>">
<% }); %>
...
```

If a user visits `/example/food`, for example, the `category` variable parameter will be equal to `"food"`. You can then pass this in to the EJS render function.

Comment: Thank you very much Sam, I think this will work, will try it out soon.